# A "to" between two verbs?

Tags: prepositions

I wrote an article with the following sentence in it, but I find it a bit strange in the part I marked bold:

> We would like to incentivize the firms in different levels of the supply chain **to reduce to eliminate** conflict mineral usage by their rational and economic deliberation, which can potentially be substantially less costly than enforcing a law that imposes stringent requirements on the firms.

I would like to say that the firms will reduce the usage until eventually eliminating the usage all together. But using "to" between two verbs seems confusing. Is this a correct way of saying it? If not, how best should I put it? I know I can replace the "to" with "or", but I think that would lose the sense that the change is gradual and also there is a general direction toward using less.

Comment: "to reduce, and eventually eliminate,"? On a different note, something _can_ be cheaper or _is potentially_ cheaper. If you say it _can potentially_, it gives me the idea you are not very sure. It might, maybe, be a possibility that could potentially happen... that sounds like I shouldn't count on it ;)

Comment: @oerkelens Thank you for the suggestion. I guess I should sound more confident over there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few ideas:

> We would like to incentivize the firms in different levels of the supply chain **to reduce—in order to eventually eliminate**—conflict mineral usage by their rational and economic deliberation, which can potentially be substantially less costly than enforcing a law that imposes stringent requirements on the firms.
>
> We would like to incentivize the firms in different levels of the supply chain **to reduce—and in time to eliminate**—conflict mineral usage by their rational and economic deliberation, which can potentially be substantially less costly than enforcing a law that imposes stringent requirements on the firms.
>
> We would like to incentivize the firms in different levels of the supply chain **to reduce—with an eye to eliminating**—conflict mineral usage by their rational and economic deliberation, which can potentially be substantially less costly than enforcing a law that imposes stringent requirements on the firms.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if my original wording is grammatically wrong? I'd appreciate it if some explanations can be given.

Comment: @FangJing, yes, I would say it was wrong. Certain verbs can be followed by an infinitive. (Examples: I will **try** to sleep. I would **like** to taste the cake.) But **reduce** is not one of them.